# Не работает селектор this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно взять значение из заголовка и вставить его в значение атрибута

Но в каждом посте есть свой заголовок и мне нужно чтобы он для каждого поста вставлял свое занчение

```
// Post Headline
let post = $('.post');
let headline = post.find('h3').text();

post.ready(function(){
    $('.post').attr('data-headline', headline);
});
```

Comment: `html` добавьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.post').attr('data-headline', function () { return $(this).find("h3").text() })
```

```css
.post::before {
  content: attr(data-headline) "\a0";
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=post><h3>abc</h3></div>
<div class=post><h3>efg</h3></div>
<div class=post><h3>hij</h3></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы очень выручили меня, все заработало, спасибо за оперативность.

Comment: @Serj, в таком случае стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.